# Getting error connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443 using ingress-nginx-controller service to send request from service to service from same namespace

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, load-balancing, ingress-nginx

I'm using docker_desktop on windows machine, and using ingress-nginx loadbalencer to allow traffic from client server to internal pods. For sending request from service to service inside the kubernetes cluster in the same namespace, I'm using ingress-nginx-controller service which is on ingress-nginx(load-balancer) namespace, and getting the error connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443.

I've added ingress-service setup yaml file:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - mysite.dev
      secretName: mysite-dev-tls
  rules:
    - host: mysite.dev
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /api/lists/?(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: lists-srv
                port:
                  number: 3000
          - path: /?(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: client-srv
                port:
                  number: 3000
```